# Trigger that fires a rule is erroring

Tags: sql-server, procedure, eventtrigger

I have a trigger that calls a database procedure which logs all changes to every column in a particular table but when the trigger fires I get an error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure dp_PolicyBenefit_audit, Line 0
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to int.

I have an `INSERT` and `UPDATE` trigger for every column in `PolicyBenefit`, 100 in all - the code below shows just one

```
drop procedure if exists dp_PolicyBenefit_audit
GO

create procedure dp_PolicyBenefit_audit
  @p_policy_id               varchar(20),
  @p_id                      int,
  @p_benefit_cd              char(4),
  @p_seq                     smallint,
  @p_operation               varchar(10),
  @p_description             varchar(100),
  @p_old_value               varchar(20),
  @p_new_value               varchar(20)
AS

  if (@p_operation = 'INSERT')
  begin
    insert into PolicyBenefitAudit
    (
        PolicyNo,
        EntityNo,
        BenefitCode,
        BenefitSequence,
        Description,
        OldValue,
        NewValue,
        CreatedBy, 
        CreatedDate
    )
    values
    (
      @p_policy_id,
      @p_id,
      @p_benefit_cd,
      @p_seq,
      @p_description,
      null,
      @p_new_value,
      user_name(),
      getdate()
    )
  end


  if (@p_operation = 'UPDATE') and isnull(@p_old_value,'') != isnull(@p_new_value,''))
  begin
    insert into PolicyBenefitAudit
    (
        PolicyNo,
        EntityNo,
        BenefitCode,
        BenefitSequence,
        Description,
        OldValue,
        NewValue,
        CreatedBy, 
        CreatedDate
    )
    values
    (
      @p_policy_id, 
      @p_id,
      @p_benefit_cd, 
      @p_seq,
      @p_description,
      @p_old_value,
      @p_new_value,
      user_name(),
      getdate()
    )
  end

GO


drop trigger if exists dt_PolicyBenefit_OccupationCode_upd
GO

create trigger dt_PolicyBenefit_OccupationCode_upd on PolicyBenefit
after update as
begin
    declare
        @old_OccupationCode varchar(100)
    select @old_OccupationCode = cast(OccupationCode as varchar(100)) from deleted
    exec dp_PolicyBenefit_audit @p_policy_id = PolicyNo, 
     @p_id = EntityNo, 
    @p_benefit_cd = BenefitCode, 
    @p_seq = BenefitSequence,
         @p_operation = 'UPDATE',
         @p_description = 'Occupational Per Mille loading duration (in years)',
         @p_old_value = @old_OccupationCode,
         @p_new_value = OccupationCode
end
GO
```

Expecting procedure to insert a row into the `PolicyBenefitAudit` table

Comment: the error message is very clear. Double check your source & destination column data type.

Comment: You are inserting a string value for an 'int' field.

Comment: Start over. No one can help you debug code that is syntactically incorrect and cannot be created. Your trigger attempts to pass values to the procedure that do not exist - OccupationCode, BenefitSequence, EntityNo, PolicyNo. In addition, you just are not paying attention - is Occupation Code varchar 100 (as defined in trigger) or varchar  20 (as defined in procedure - which a pointlessly vague name)?

Comment: And you make the classic mistake of assuming a single row is affected by the statement that executes the trigger. There might be zero rows, 1 row, or many, many rows.

Comment: Solved:  The syntax is fine - OccupationCode, BenefitSequence, EntityNo and PolicyNo are all columns NOT parameters. The varchar(100) should be varchar(20) but thats not the problem either. The issue was the parameter p_type should have been p_benefit_cd - a rename to due our conversion of our INGRES DBMS to SQLServer .... Also if there are multiple rows I want multiple rows inserted

Comment: Actually the auditting is inserting OK BUT the columns that are being passed are being treated as strings - so 'PolicyNo' is inserted into PolicyBenefitAudit rather than the value of the column PolicyNo - is the only way to additionally select them as I have the old values ?   Jesus .. this is so much easier to do in Ingres  ....

Answer (score 0):

The error is in passing parameters into your sp:

```
exec dp_PolicyBenefit_audit @p_policy_id = PolicyNo, 
 @p_id = EntityNo, 
@p_benefit_cd = BenefitCode, 
@p_seq = BenefitSequence,
     @p_operation = 'UPDATE',
     @p_description = 'Occupational Per Mille loading duration (in years)',
     @p_old_value = @old_OccupationCode,
     @p_new_value = OccupationCode
```

Your `@p_id` is declared as `int`, and you pass `EntityNo` (string) to it.
This cause "Error converting data type nvarchar to int", `EntityNo` is nvarchar.

Comment: EntityNo is an int thats not the problem

Comment: @Colin Hay You are wrong, your code `@p_id = EntityNo` is equivalent to `@p_id = 'EntityNo'` since EntityNo is not a field but a string constant, even if it's not enclosed in " ' "

Answer (score 0):

Did away with database procedures all together and coded it in 50 triggers like this:

```
create trigger dt_PolicyBenefit_OccupationalPerMilleLoadingDuration on PolicyBenefit
after insert, update as
begin
    insert into PolicyBenefitAudit
    (
        PolicyNo,
        EntityNo,
        BenefitCode,
        BenefitSequence,
        Description,
        OldValue,
        NewValue,
        CreatedBy,
        CreatedDate
    )
    select i.PolicyNo,
           i.EntityNo,
           i.BenefitCode,
           i.BenefitSequence,
           'Occupational Per Mille loading duration (in years)',
           d.OccupationalPerMilleLoadingDuration,
           i.OccupationalPerMilleLoadingDuration,
           user_name(),
           getdate()
    from   inserted i left join deleted d
    on     i.PolicyBenefitId = d.PolicyBenefitId
    where  i.OccupationalPerMilleLoadingDuration != d.OccupationalPerMilleLoadingDuration;
end
GO
```